# What does "ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 279936 into shape (529,529)" mean?

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, kaggle

I was trying to run some RNN code.

```
    # Original Dimensions

    #ratio = 4

    #image_width = int(image_width / ratio)
    #image_height = int(image_height / ratio)

    channels = 1
    nb_classes = 1

    dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(train_files), 64, 64), dtype=np.float32)

    i = 0
    counter = 0

    for _file in train_files:
        if(counter <= 34000):
            img = Image.open(folder + "/" + _file)
            img = img.reduce(8)
            img = img.convert("1")
            #img = load_img(folder + "/" + _file, color_mode="grayscale")  # this is a PIL image
            # Convert to Numpy Array
            x = img_to_array(img, data_format = "channels_last")  
            x = x.reshape((4096, 4374))
            # Normalize
            x = (x - 128.0) / 128.0
            dataset[i] = x
            i += 1
            counter += 1
            if i % 1000 == 0:
                print("%d images to array" % i)
```

After I ran it, I got a "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4096,4374) into shape (64,64)". How can I fix this?

Comment: To be capable of being reshaped into a 529 by 529 square, your image data would have to contain exactly 279841 pixels.  Your data somehow contains 95 pixels more than that; perhaps it measures 486x576 or 432x648 pixels?

Comment: Hi, after doing this, I get an error , "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4096,4374) into shape (64,64)"

Answer (score 0):

If you divide `279936` by `529` you'll get `529.1795841210`, it's **ALMOST** a perfect square.

You can't resize a square matrix of size Nx1 to a matrix of size MxM if `N` is not equal to `M^2` (is not a perfect square).

Your issue lays in your image or in `img_to_array` function. Please, ensure that those have/return the proper dimensions.